# Haskell Could not find module 'Random' when running GHCI, what should I do

Tags: haskell, random

This is a guess number code. 
when I run it, I got an error : could not find the module 'Random'. what should I do ?

```
module Main where 

import IO
import Random

main = do 
       hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
       num <- randomRIO (1::Int, 100)
       putStrLn "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100"
       doGuessing num = do
           putStrLn "Enter your guess:"
           guess <- getLine
           let guessNum = read guess
           if guessNum < num
              then do putStrLn "Too Low!"
                   doGuessing num
           else if guessNum > num
              then do putStrLn "Too High"
                   doGuessing num
           else do putStrLn "You Win!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using

```
import System.IO
import System.Random
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Install `random` package. The easiest way to do this is to use `cabal`

```
cabal install random
```

Comment: How to do that? just adding this code or? could you explain it in detail? thanks so much

Comment: cabal is a system for managing haskell packages. If you are using linux, just install it from your distro's package manager (e.g. `sudo apt-get install cabal` in Ubuntu). I'm not familiar with Haskell development on Windows at all, so I can't help you in this case

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid No, it is no longer included in GHC version 7.2.1 http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/release-7-2-1.html#id569450